# passportjs deserializeUser nothing happen after call

Tags: node.js, express, orm, passport.js

am using nodejs and express with passportJS to auth my users with **session** (very important to use session in my case)

basically, i have a dashboard and I want to auth each request using isLoggedIn middleware

after the user logged in, the function (deserializeUser) get running and run the findById but nothing happened after that !!!

below my code

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// required for passport

app.use(session({ secret: 'anything' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

    console.log("serializeUser =>"+user);

    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("Deaire ==>"+id);

    models.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {

        if(user)
            return done(false,user);
        return done(false,false);

    });
});

passport.use(new UniqueTokenStrategy({
        session: true},
    function (token, done) {
        models.User.findOne({where: {token: token}}).then(function (user) {
            models.userHasRoles.findOne({

                where: {

                    userId: user.id


                }
            }).then(function (hasRoles) {


                if (!hasRoles) {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        })
    }

));

passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'phone_number',
        passwordField: 'pin',
        session: true,
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req,phone_number, pin, done) {

        console.log("Inside local str");

        models.PhoneVerification.findOne({ where: {phoneNumber: phone_number, pinCode:pin}}).then(function (phoneVerification) {

            if(phoneVerification==null){

                models.configuration.findOne({
                    where:{name :"default pin"}
                }).then(function (configuration) {

                    if(configuration.detail==pin){

                    }else {

                        return done(null, false, {message: "Couldn't login"});
                    }
                })
            }
            models.User.findOne({where: {phoneNumber: phone_number}}).then(function (user) {

                if(user == null){

                    models.User.create({
                        phoneNumber: phone_number,
                        token: randtoken.generate(32)
                    }).then(function (user) {

                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                }else {

                    user.update({token: randtoken.generate(32)}).then(function () {

                        return done(null, user);
                    });

                }
            });
        })
    }
));
```

so till now everthing is good , i can check if am not logged in , but if i am really logged in then the code get idle there

here is my middleware to check the session

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

console.log("first auth");

// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();

}
```

so when am trying to check iof am logged in or not i get the following from console

> Deaire ==>17152 Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `firstName`,
>   `lastName`, `phoneNumber`, `photo`, `token`, `deviceToken`, `osInfo`,
>   `actualLat`, `actualLng`, `cityId`, `countryId`, `status`,
>   `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` =
>   17152;

Comment: Note: after I get from the console, nothing happen, even the return back it's not working !!!!! , this is my problem

Comment: Does the `models.User.findById` return any user? Or an error?

Comment: nothing happen after calling findById , but i took the raw query from console and try it manually and works perfectly :( unfortunately not in the app

Comment: What orm are you using the manage your models?

Comment: sequlize and mysql for DB

Comment: I have never used sequelize, so maybe I can't help properly. But did you try to call `models.User.findById` using promise? Like this: `models.User.findById(id).then(function(user){ /* call done function here */ })`. Thats is how I saw in the doc examples.

Comment: yes i do , i put a console.log inside the function and never get called !!! so the code just run the findById and stop there

Comment: If you call `models.User.findById` in another place (outside for deserializeUser), does it work?

Comment: yes works fine , but inside deserializeUser not working

Comment: i tried different code and still same issue , nothing happen after calling deserializeUser , any help plz :(

Comment: Are you sure the connection it's opened when deserializeUser  it's called? An error would be thrown in this case, but worth the shot!

Comment: yes it's work , now 4 days trying to solve the issue without any progress :(